# Is there a way to make TypeScript honor tabs?

Tags: typescript

It seems that typescript ignores tab settings for JavaScript files and inserts spaces instead of tabs in the generated js file.

Is there a setting to force tabs instead of spaces?

P.S. Using VS 2013 Update 4

Comment: TypeScript has nothing to do with tabs or spaces. Those are all editor settings. If you mention what you're using as a Text Editor, we might be able to better help you.

Comment: Which IDE/editor are you using? There are several. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#IDE_and_editor_support

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Visual Studio 2013, Update 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workaround solution from [S-YOU] in typescript issues thread might be useful until typescript team allow to modify through tsconfig.json:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4042

For those who just want to change the output to tab, you can patch typescript.js after you install.

```
sed -i 's/"    "/"\\t"/g' node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js

% grep "indentStrings =" node_modules/typescript -R

node_modules/typescript/lib/typescriptServices.js: var indentStrings = ["", "    "];
node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js: var indentStrings = ["", "\t"];
node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary.js: var indentStrings = ["", "    "];
node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js: var indentStrings = ["", "    "];
node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js: var indentStrings = ["", "    "];
```

if you want to change `indentString` to something you prefer change in those files the 2nd string to whatever you want.

Comment: I find it really annoying how `microsoft` locks almost all GitHub issues on the TypeScript project. In other words, "STFU, we've decided this and won't budge even if in the future things change"

Answer (score 9):

The indentation emitted by the compiler [appears to be hardcoded](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6ca9d04b60fd3861ed595e968e266f5ef19b29f2/src/compiler/utilities.ts#L3267).

So no, you can't configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Old issue but since this is still relevant, I find that adding  `&& prettier --write ./dist` to your `build` command would be a better option, since TypeScript output doesn't seem to be well-formatted even if you patch the TypeScript library files. Plus, when you deploy to Heroku, the deployment environment handles package installation and build; so this gives you control over the output even then.